# VBA: How do i write a macro for auto correcting date?

Tags: vba, excel, excel-formula

[image]

I have tried using the Record Macro function but nothing was being recorded

Comment: how about just use `DATEVALUE` formula?

Comment: select all the cells to correct, hover over the first one and correct. or just use the Record Macro button

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can iterate over the Worksheet.SmartTags.

```
Sub FixDates()
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Dim DateTag As SmartTag
    For Each DateTag In ActiveSheet.SmartTags

        If DateTag = "urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:smarttags#date" Then

            DateTag.Range.Value = CDate(DateTag.Range.Value)

            DateTag.Delete

        End If

    Next
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks. I wish to learn more about the SmartTags. Do you have link that explains most of the commonly used ones?

Comment: Thanks for the check mark!  Here is a good reference: [Working Smarter With SmartTags](http://www.journalofaccountancy.com/issues/2002/nov/worksmarterwithsmarttags.html).